# PHP laravel automatic routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.5 and I am trying to use a automatic route to the controller but it isn't working

In the web.php(the routing file for this version) 
I have the follow line

```
Route::resource('panel', 'panel');
Route::resource('/', 'HomeController');
```

In the panel I have the follow actions

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class panel extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        return \View::make('panel.index');
    }

    public function registrar(){
        return \View::make('panel.registrar');
    }

}
```

but it's only calling the `index()` view
the registrar() view is not being called when user acess the url

```
site.com/panel/registrar
```

the follow erro is printing in the screen

```
"Method [show] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\panel]."
```

I tried to use the base_controller but it don't work too

```
"Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Base_Controller' not found"
```

is there an way  to identify these actions ?

Comment: basically we dont have 'automatic' routing in the way you are talking about it, it isn't a thing any more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource routing sets up 7 specific routes, that is 7 specific methods you need on the controller, 7. If you dont want all 7 of those routes you have to define it that way.

Resource routing is not implicit controllers. It does not look at the method on the controller then make routes .. Resource routing is a 'specific' thing. We do not have implicit controllers any more in Laravel as there is really no point.

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Controllers - Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)

You have routes that are created that point to methods that don't exist, that is what the error is.

Also, the first argument to `Route::resource` is a resource 'name', not a PATH. It is not technically a URI. It is a name of a resource.

```
Route::resource('/', ...) // not a name
```

Comment: I just saw all three answers, all three explains , giving reason and solution to the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a resource controller with basic CRUD operations, so in order to work you have to define the rest methods like in your case you should add a method `show()` and then render the view you want in that method.

A resource controller must have the following methods defined:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And base controller obviusly it is not `Base_Controller` but its `Controller`

For more please reffer here [Laravel 5.5 Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)

Answer (score 2):

Change this resourse to simple `get` , if you don't need all resource methods

```
  Route::get('/panel', 'panel@index');
  Route::get('/panel/registrar', 'panel@registrar');
```

And use `home` instead just `/` to get unconflicted url

```
 Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
```

Comment: yes, in reality they should not be using resource routing at all, most likely